# How to remove the pause between audio tracks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am building a javascript game, and i want to create a background music based on sound file snippets. Short mp3 files to play them as one continuous track. I have tried binding an "ended" event handler on the audio file, though this causes a delay between audio fragments.

To solve this I made a hacky solution that still does not work, changing the audio 1 second before it finishes.

```
Ebuc.manageAudio = function(){
    var listener = function (event) {
         if (this.currentTime > (this.duration - 1) && Ebuc.bgnext) {
             Ebuc.manageAudio();
             console.log("aduio");
             Ebuc.bgnext = false;
         }
         if(this.currentTime < 2){
            Ebuc.bgnext = true;
             console.log("reset");
         }
        console.log(event);
        console.log("listener active")

    };
    var color = Level.current.color;
    if(Ebuc.bgsong == null) {
        Ebuc.bgsong = new Audio('assets/sound/' + Resources.audioSetList[color].getcurrentsong());
        Ebuc.bgsong.addEventListener('timeupdate', listener, true);

    }
    else{
        Ebuc.bgsong = new Audio('assets/sound/' + Resources.audioSetList[color].getcurrentsong());
    }

    Ebuc.bgsong.play();
    Resources.audioSetList[color].next();

};
```

This sample works once, when it is time to switch fragment 2 to fragment 3 the loop stops. Console logging the event listener gives 4 times a log before stopping.

Q1: Why is this eventlistener suddenly disappearing?
Q2: Is there a non hack solution for chaining these audio fragments.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You're going to have more than just pausing issues trying to rapidly switch between two short audio clips, you're going to probably want to crossfade between the two audio tracks quickly as well to prevent any popping, artifacts, etc.

Here's an example of crossfading using howler from [howler's github issues.](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/146) You could probably use this example, and keep a queue of loaded instances to transition to. I hope that helps.

```
//you'll probably want this crossfade duration to be shorter.
var crossfadeDuration = 5000,
    volume            = 0.7;

var instance1, instance2, soundDuration;

// Singleton helper to build similar instances
var createHowlerInstance = function (urls, onload) {
  return new Howl({
    urls: urls,
    loop: false,
    volume: 0,
    onload: onload
  });
};

// Create "slave" instance. This instance is meant
// to be played after the first one is done.
instance2 = createHowlerInstance(['file2.mp3']);

// Create "master" instance. The onload function passed to
// the singleton creator will coordinate the crossfaded loop
instance1 = createHowlerInstance(['file1.mp3'], function(){

  // Get the sound duration in ms from the Howler engine
  soundDuration = Math.floor(instance1._duration * 1000);

  (function crossfadedLoop(enteringInstance, leavingInstance){

    // Fade in entering instance
    enteringInstance.pos(0).play().fade(0, volume, crossfadeDuration);

    // Wait for the audio end to fade out entering instance
    // white fading in leaving instance
    setTimeout(function(){

      enteringInstance.fade(volume, 0, crossfadeDuration);
      crossfadedLoop(leavingInstance, enteringInstance);

    }, soundDuration - crossfadeDuration);

  })(instance1, instance2);

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though it does not answer the question. The problem is the delays in event listeners, simply fading in en out the files beats the purpose of this modular sound loop.

Comment: It's not "simply fading in and out", it's called a crossfade, and it's how you smoothly connect two pieces of audio that aren't part of a continuous waveform. In your case, it would be very, very short, and would smoothly transition between audio files without the delay you're currently experiencing. For those few ms, the two files would be playing at the same time. That may not answer your first question, but it is definitely a non-hack way of achieving what you're asking.


    `setTimeout(function(){...}, soundDuration - crossfadeDuration)`


is what solves your delay problem.

Comment: So while file1 is fading out, file2 is fading in.

Answer (score 3):

By using the idea of setting a timeOut in the answer of pantalohnes I have created the following code to solve the gap:

```
Ebuc.manageAudio = function(){
        var color = Level.current.color;
        Ebuc.bgsong = new Audio('assets/sound/' + Resources.audioSetList[color].getcurrentsong());
        Ebuc.bgsong.addEventListener("loadedmetadata",function(){
            setTimeout(Ebuc.manageAudio, (Ebuc.bgsong.duration * 1000) - 50);
            Ebuc.bgsong.play();
            console.log(Ebuc.bgsong.duration);
            Resources.audioSetList[color].next();
        });
    };
```

The 50 milliseconds timeout bridges the gap between the sequenced files exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question (although I see you found another solution), I think I found your bug:

The second time your enter Ebuc.manageAudio(), Ebuc.bgsong is already set and you just create a new Audio `Ebuc.bgsong = new Audio(...)` without attaching the listener to it, so you're not being notified for any 'timeupdate' events emitted when playing the second audio file.

You should also remove the listener from the previous playing audio.

So, if all else is ok, I think this should fix it:

```
Ebuc.manageAudio = function(){
    var listener = function (event) {
        if (this.currentTime > (this.duration - 1) && Ebuc.bgnext) {
            Ebuc.manageAudio();
            console.log("aduio");
            Ebuc.bgnext = false;
        }
        if(this.currentTime < 2){
            Ebuc.bgnext = true;
            console.log("reset");
        }
        console.log(event);
        console.log("listener active")

    };
    var color = Level.current.color;
    if(Ebuc.bgsong != null) {
        Ebuc.bgsong.removeEventListener('timeupdate', listener, true);
    }
    Ebuc.bgsong = new Audio('assets/sound/' + Resources.audioSetList[color].getcurrentsong());
    Ebuc.bgsong.addEventListener('timeupdate', listener, true);

    Ebuc.bgsong.play();
    Resources.audioSetList[color].next();

};
```

More than that, I think that if you properly remove the listener from the previous playing audio, you won't need that bgnext hack at all:

```
var listener = function (event) {
    if (this.currentTime > (this.duration - 1)) {
        Ebuc.manageAudio();
        console.log("aduio");
    }
    console.log(event);
    console.log("listener active")
};

Ebuc.manageAudio = function () {
    var color = Level.current.color;
    if (Ebuc.bgsong != null) {
        Ebuc.bgsong.removeEventListener('timeupdate', listener, true);
    }
    Ebuc.bgsong = new Audio('assets/sound/' + Resources.audioSetList[color].getcurrentsong());
    Ebuc.bgsong.addEventListener('timeupdate', listener, true);

    Ebuc.bgsong.play();
    Resources.audioSetList[color].next();

};
```

Let me know if that worked :)