# How can I switch Web Audio Source Nodes without clicking?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to write a small Audio library for a specific web application, to solve the problem of Web Audio Buffer Sources requiring long load times, I'm trying to switch a HTML5 Audio Source(via MediaElementSourceNode) with a Buffer Source once the Buffer Source is ready to play. with a 20 minute track, it takes Web Audio's Buffer Source roughly 5 seconds to decode and start playing.

using MediaElementSourceNode is required for using the PanNode in Web Audio

First, I thought it was a JS main thread Latency issue that was throwing off the "start Time". I thought I could solve by making sure the code that disables MediaElementSource and enables BufferSourceNode are as close to execution as possible.

Then, I though it must be the HTML having a small delay when it starts, causing the recorded startTime to be off, to get around this, I used a Event Handler listening for 'play'.

I searched around and discovered Gapless 5 apparently did this without issue, looking at its source code, i could not discovered how it is switching sources seamlessly

```
 play(offset) {
        this.createNodes();
        this.connectNodes();
        //if webAudio's buffer source is not ready, starting playing with HTML5
    if (!this.audioClip.isWebAudioReady() &&
        this.audioClip.playType > 0) {
        this.playHTML5();
    }
    //returns true if buffer != null
    if (!this.audioClip.isWebAudioReady()) {
        this.audioClip.addDecodeListener(this.play.bind(this));
    }

    if (this.audioClip.isWebAudioReady()) {
        this.playBufferSource();

    }
 playHTML5() {
    var context = AudioManager.context();
    if (this.audioClip.isHTML5Ready()) {
        this.createHTMLSourceNode();
        console.log("playing HTML5");
        this.mediaElementSourceNode.connect(this.gainNode);
        this.mediaElementSourceNode.source.play();
        this.startTime = context.currentTime;


    }
    else {
        console.log('not ready yet');
        this.audioClip.addLoadListener(this.playHTML5.bind(this));
    }
}
playBufferSource() {
    var context = AudioManager.context();
    var offset = context.currentTime - this.startTime;
    if (!this.bufferSourceNode) {
        this.createBufferSourceNode();
    }
    this.bufferSourceNode.connect(this.gainNode);
    //hoplessly attempt to make up for Thread latencey
    offset = context.currentTime - this.startTime;

    if (this.audioClip.playType > 0) {
        this.mediaElementSourceNode.disconnect();
        this.mediaElementSourceNode = null;
    }
    if (this.audioClip.playType == 0) {
        offset = 0;
        this.bufferSourceNode.start(0, offset);
    }
    else {
        offset = context.currentTime - this.startTime;
        this.bufferSourceNode.start(0, offset);
    }

    // console.log("starting web audio at" + offset);
}
createBufferSourceNode() {
    var context = AudioManager.context();
    if (!this.audioClip.webAudioReady) {
        console.log('Web Audio not ready!, Sometihng went wrong!');
        return;

    }
    var buffer = this.audioClip.buffer;
    this.bufferSourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
    //When using anything other than Buffer, 
    //we want to disable pitching.
    if (this.audioClip.playType == NS.PlayTypes.Buffer) {
        this.bufferSourceNode.playbackRate.setValueAtTime(this._pitch,
            context.currentTime);

    }
    this.bufferSourceNode.buffer = buffer;
}


createHTMLSourceNode() {
    var context = AudioManager.context();
    var HTMLAudio = this.audioClip.mediaElement.cloneNode(false);

    //HTMLAudio.addEventListener('ended', onHTML5Ended.bind(this), false);
    HTMLAudio.addEventListener('play', this.onHTML5Play.bind(this), false);

    var sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(HTMLAudio);

    sourceNode.source = HTMLAudio;
    this.mediaElementSourceNode = sourceNode;

}
/**
 * 
 */
onHTML5Play() {
    this.startTime = AudioManager.context().currentTime;
    console.log("HTML5 started playing");
}
```

Since I'm starting the second source as close as possible in time with the first, I should technically not hear any clicks if the waveform line up close enough, but the resulting clicks are very audible, sometimes 2 clicks are audible.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the audio clips themselves. If this is for a specific use case you could just make sure your audio clips start and end on a zero-crossing. This can be achieved in any audio editor worth its snuff. (Do the audio clips click when played apart or in an outside media player?)

Comment: @Trobol the goal is to play the same clip with one source(HTML5) while the other source (WebAudio) is still loading (takes a while on some machines) the same clip then turn off the first source midtrack and play the second seamlessly , the problem is i don't know when the Buffer Source will be ready to play to make it start a zero crossing.

technically i could make both sources wait until they hit a zero crossing before i make the second source play. but the problem with that is HTML Audio doesn't have sample-level precision, neither does AudioContext.currentTime if using FireFox

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36200656/8781351

Comment: @Trobol the cross fade one? I see, I'm going to try that now and see how i go.

Comment: @Trobol
Okay, it turns out, switching isn't the issue here, whats happening HTML5 audio becomes choppy and stutters the moment i set the buffer on the Buffer Source before i play it. don't know if there's anyithng doable about that